# How to override vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/items/column/name.phtml Magento 2

Tags: magento2.2

Can anyone help how to override

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/items/column/name.phtml file.
```

Answer (score 4):

At Magento2, from 7 layout  `items/column/name.phtml` called

- sales_order_creditmemo_new.xml
- sales_order_creditmemo_updateqty.xml
- sales_order_creditmemo_view.xml
- sales_order_invoice_new.xml
- sales_order_invoice_updateqty.xml
- sales_order_invoice_view.xml
- sales_order_view.xml

That you need to identify for which page, you want rewrite `name.phtml`.

So, you  will found **out respective layout  file and have to   create that layout file on your custom module** as  mention by [Michell](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/242228/4564) process.

Suppose, you want to changes at invoice create page.
Then have to create

1.**app/code/Company/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_invoice_new.xml**

**Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="column_name" template="Company_Module::orders/items/column/name.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Yes Correct, it is called multiple instances.

Comment: @Amit : above code working but if we are going to shipment of order then this is not working. For name.phtml which xml we should override?

Answer (score 2):

This is very simple, follow my guide below :

Step 1 : create file :

> app/code/Company/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml

With content :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="column_name">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Company_Module::orders/items/column/name.phtml</argument>
            </action> 
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Step 2 : create phtml file :

> app/code/Company/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/orders/items/column/name.phtml

```
Then put your code here
```

Comment: Does it work on your end?

Comment: Yes, it works on my end

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make
app/design/adminhtml/templates/items/column/name.phtml(write your custom code here)

then do setup upgrade and setup static-content deploy

> php bin/magento s:up
>
> php bin/magento s:s:d

Comment: it's rare to create a theme for admin, I don't think that it's the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

override templates(.phtml) using custom theme

if you want to override `vendor\magento\module-sales\view\adminhtml\templates\items\name.phtml` first you need to create your custom theme, please refer this [link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html) for how to create a custom theme.

after that create phtml file in your custom theme to override the default one

```
 app/design/frontend/vendor-name/theme-name/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/some.phtml
```

finally, clear the cache of Magento as well as the browser, then check your page, new phtml file only reflected.

in this way you can override templates

Best of Luck!

Comment: Thanks, but I'm referring on overriding the template from the admin's end.

Comment: then your file will be here

magento\app\design\adminhtml\YourVendor\YourThemeName\Magento_Backend\view\adminhtml\templates\product\some.phtml

Comment: Up vote my answer if helpful..
your welcome :)

Comment: I already upvote it. But it will not reflect publicly since I have a low reputation.

Comment: He is looking for `admin` template, how do you want him to put it on` frontend` as you response ?

Comment: For override admin template i have already mentioned in above comment. @prince

Comment: we are referring to the answer, not the comments

Answer (score 0):

I figured it how to achieve. I just created a theme specifically for backend and from there I extend the module.